# Camel Consumer: Dynamic Delay Times

Tags: java, apache-camel

I've been trying to find and test different solutions to a problem I have found with Camel's delay attribute. It seems that the Camel delay is only capable of being set at run time. I have tested this using the following code and updating the variable 'CAMEL_DELAY_TIME_IN_MILLI_SECONDS' during subsequent polls.

```
        from(incomingEndpoint)
            .delay(CAMEL_DELAY_TIME_IN_MILLI_SECONDS)
            .threads(MAX_NUMBER_OF_CAMEL_THREADS)
            .process((exchange) -> {...
```

My question is revolving around Camels capability to have a dynamic delay. Is there a method which allows a developer to create a function to define this? Do Camel users solve this issue by adding a thread.sleep function within process to create an make-shift delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression in the delay where you can use any of the Camel languages (http://camel.apache.org/languages), such as calling a method on a bean with the bean language (http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html):

```
from(...)   
  .delay(method(MyClass.class, "myMethodName"))   
  ...
```

Then in the bean method you can return any dynamic value you like. Or if you want to compute the value based on some information from the message, you can do that as well and have bean parameter binding (http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) to pass in such information, or try to see if the simple language (http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm... I did try to reference a method from the same class as the route, but I did not specify a class like you have shown above. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Can confirm that this syntax works. Thanks for the bonus info too.